# Плавное появление модального окна

Tags: jquery

Использую magnific popup на [сайте](http://vsebe.info/) для всех модальных окон. Как сделать плавное их появление. Может есть настройка плагина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [официальной документации](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

CSS

```
/* overlay at start */
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
}
/* overlay animate in */
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-ready {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* overlay animate out */
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-removing {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* content at start */
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap .mfp-content {
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
}
/* content animate it */
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-ready .mfp-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* content animate out */
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-removing .mfp-content {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

При инициализации `magnificPopup` в объект добавить

```
mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
```

Пример инициализации

```
$('.popup-link').magnificPopup({
  removalDelay: 350,
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
});
```

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZYZMp

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовый сниппет. Добавьте в CSS следующее:

```
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
    background: #00;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-ready    { opacity: .9; }
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-removing { opacity: 0; }

.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap .mfp-content {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-ready .mfp-content    { opacity: 1; }
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-removing .mfp-content { opacity: 0; }
```